# Disable users of a database not Logins in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-administration

To disable users of a Database in SQL Server 2008, I gave the command:

```
Use Database
Go
Revoke Connect from username;
```

It works for the users with *SQL Server Authentication* such as **abcdef**.

But not for the user with *Windows Authentication* such as **DomainName\abcdef**. It gives the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '\'.

It does not even work by using the single quotes around the username in the above mentioned command.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 18):

It worked when I used the double quotes around the username such as:

```
USE Database
GO
REVOKE CONNECT FROM "domain\user"
```

To enable users of a database:

```
USE Database
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO "username"
```

To disable Logins of a server:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER LOGIN loginname DISABLE;
```

To enable Logins of a server:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER LOGIN loginname ENABLE;
```

Comment: That presumably requires `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`. Using the SQL Server quotes of square brackets `[like this]` would work already without requiring that.

Answer (score 0):

I identify the disabled users by using the sys.sysusers DMV

you can see on the example below. the result of the query, and further below, navigating through ssms.

```
select * from sys.sysusers 
where islogin =1
  and hasdbaccess = 0
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The question is how to disable Windows-authenticated users, not how to identify already-disabled users.